# How to compare Moment.js date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to compare `Moment.js` date? I have JSON in which there is a "date", how can I compare today with what is in the "date"?

My Json:

```
{
   date: "2020-03-29 17:03:04"
}
```

My code:

```
moment(MYJSON).isSame(moment().format('L') // false
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. What exactly are you trying to compare anyway? Just the date?

Comment: should be something like `moment(MYJSON.date).isSame(moment(), 'day')`

Answer (score 0):

Use moment().isSame() to check if a moment is the same as another moment. The first argument will be parsed as a moment, if not already so.

Passing in month will check month and year. Passing in day will check day, month, and year

Docs: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/02-is-same/

```js
var input = "2020-03-29 17:03:04";
console.log(moment(input).isSame("2020-12-31", "year"));
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```